# Issues with helm install Orion Context Broker

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I'm trying to install FIWARE Orion on AKS using your Helm chart. I installed MongoDB using

helm repo add azure-marketplace https://marketplace.azurecr.io/helm/v1/repo
helm install my-release azure-marketplace/mongodb

Consequently I configured the MongoDB in values.yaml as follows:

```
## database configuration
  db:
    # -- configuration of the mongo-db hosts. if multiple hosts are inserted, its assumed that mongo is running as a replica set
    hosts: [my-release-mongodb]
    #   - my-release-mongodb
    # -- the db to use. if running in multiservice mode, its used as a prefix.
    name: orion
    # -- Database authentication (not needed if MongoDB doesn't use --auth)
    auth:
      # --user for connecting mongo
      user: root
      # -- password to be used on mongo
      password: mypasswd
      # -- the MongoDB authentication mechanism to use in the case user and password is set
      #mech: SCRAM-SHA-1
```

I use the command : helm install test orion

As I see this error in the pod logging I suppose something is wrong;

```
kubectl logs test-orion-7dfcc9c7fb-8vbgw
time=2021-05-28T19:50:29.737Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=mongocContextCachePersist.cpp[59]:mongocContextCachePersist | msg=Database Error (persisting context: command insert requires authentication)
```

Can you help me with this please?

Kind regards,
Johan,

Comment: How do you configure Orion? Could you edit your question to include also that fragment, please?

Comment: Moreover... which Orion version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

you should assure that mongo-db is actually available at "my-release-mongodb:27017", you can use "kubectl get services" for that. Beside that, assure that "root:mypasswd" are actually the credentials setup at mongodb.